# Unhandled Rejection - passport login app node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm creating `nodejs` login app and using `passport` js for authentication. I use a local mysql database and use `sequelize` as ORM library.

In my user model, I have created to get the user by username.

```
module.exports.findUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
  User.findOne({ where: {username: username} }).then(function(user) {
    var userObj = user.get({plain:true});
    callback(userObj);
  })
};
```

In router file

```
passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {

        User.findUserByUsername(username, function (err, user) {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(user);
        })
    }
));
```

I'm getting an error `Unhandled rejection (<{object_values...>, no stack trace)`

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change callback calling like this :

```
callback(null, userObj);
```

In router file you `throw` when encounter to error. Throwing exception in async calling environment is not a good practice. Anyway you call `findUserByUsername` passing a callback expecting first argument is error.

In `findUserByUsername` you return user object in error place. So your logic in router file thinks it's an error.

For avoiding such these exceptions you need not to throwing exception, return them in callback functions.

Comment: Could you please explain the concept behind this?